# Error in exporting dataframe from google collab to drive (csv)

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory

I tried to save dataframe (in this case my dataframe is df_fdist) to my google drive , so I run the code like this.

```
from google.colab import files
df_fdist.to_csv('data.csv') 
files.download('data.csv')
```

However, I got this error.

```
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Do I need to declare any paths or create the csv file first in the drive?

Answer (score 2):

To save a file to your drive, you have to mount drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Save your dataframe as csv

```
df_fdist.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')
```

Read from drive

```
df_myCSV = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) All I wrong was drive directory.

Comment: Thanks! It worked in Colab when adding the path with '/content/drive/My Drive/'.